# Spring boot Task schedules to delete millions older files with parent folder

Tags: spring-boot

Wanted to delete millions of older files between 50 to 300 days, if I use simple spring task then performance overhead would also be there to delete files with folders. To delete folder which again need recursive method.

What approach would be good, any suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but here is an example of a Scheduled Task in a Spring Boot app that finds all files recursively, beginning at a root path, and then deletes any files that haven't been modified in the last 50 days.

This task runs every 10 seconds.

```
@Service
public class FileService {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void deleteFilesScheduledTask() throws IOException {
        findFiles("C:/testing");
    }

    public void findFiles(String filePath) throws IOException {
        List<File> files = Files.list(Paths.get(filePath))
                                .map(path -> path.toFile())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(File file: files) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else if(isFileOld(file)){
                deleteFile(file);
            }
        }

    }

    public void deleteFile(File file) {
        file.delete();
    }

    public boolean isFileOld(File file) {
        LocalDate fileDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(file.lastModified()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate oldDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(50);
        return fileDate.isBefore(oldDate);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea of how you can implement this functionality in your own app.

Comment: Thanks for helping, i have below code for deleting files & it's working fine, however after deleting files, also need to delete nested folder, having difficulties to delete nested folders.  And also need to know should I use Task thread pool for parallel/multi-thread processing so that performance would get improve.

Comment: Files.list(path)
    .filter(n -> (getLastModifiedTimeUnchecked(n)>= from 
        &&  getLastModifiedTimeUnchecked(n) <= till))
        .forEach(n -> {
          System.out.println(n);
          delete(n, (t, u) -> System.err.format("Couldn't delete %s%n", t, u.getMessage()));
        });

Comment: public static long getLastModifiedTimeUnchecked(Path path)
      throws UncheckedIOException {
    try {     
      long lastTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis();
     
      return lastTime;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
  }

  public static void delete(Path path, BiConsumer<Path, Exception> e) {
    try {
      
        Files.delete(path); 
            
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      e.accept(path, ex);
    }
  }